# Python sqlalchemy order_by math operation (divide) does not order results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two integer columns in my DB `times_seen` and `times_answered_correctly`.
Now I want to select all elements, which have been seen more than 100 times and sort them by a math operation (`times_answered_correctly / times_seen`).

I am using following code, which works and does not give any errors:

```
top_10_hardest = db_session.query(QuizItems).filter(QuizItems.times_seen >= 100).order_by(QuizItems.times_answered_correctly / QuizItems.times_seen).all()
```

I also tried `.order_by(asc(QuizItems.times_answered_correctly / QuizItems.times_seen))` and `desc()`. The results change, but it is still ordered randomly.

```
{% for i in top_10_hardest %}
    <p> {{ i.times_answered_correctly/i.times_seen }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

gives:

```
0.9858490566037735

0.8082788671023965

0.7952941176470588

0.9202127659574468

0.7591623036649214

0.9950980392156863

0.9907621247113164

0.9905660377358491

0.39420935412026725

0.9931506849315068
```

Why it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the columns were `Integer` columns and eventhough there were no errors in the `.order_by(asc(QuizItems.times_answered_correctly / QuizItems.times_seen)` all values have been rounded to an integer, which is `1` or `0`

In the view function I displayed the results as:

```
<p> {{ i.times_answered_correctly/i.times_seen }} </p>
```

That was the first time I have done correct math, BUT before the items were ordered, remember the order function did not work because it treated the elements as integers.

**SOLUTION:**

I fixed the issue with the `cast()` function. I casted the `Integer` elements to `Float` in the `order_by()` function:

```
db_session.query(QuizItems).filter(QuizItems.times_seen >= 100).order_by(cast(QuizItems.times_answered_correctly, Float) / cast(QuizItems.times_seen, Float)).all()
```